# sbt failing to detect new .scala file

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a somewhat trivial but mysterious problem. I'm running sbt on Windows and am following along to the sbt tutorial, the specific page in question being [this one](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html). I am following it almost step by step, except naming my overall directory "test." Compile with an empty project works fine. However, ~compile fails to detect creation of Hello.scala under the src/main/scala/example subfolder, whether I do it in Notepad++, Explorer GUI or cut-and-pasting from another folder. Regular "compile" command and subsequent "run" work fine. Did I screw up my sbt installation somehow?

By the way, this is on Windows 10, if that matters.

EDIT: build.sbt is empty;
Folder structure (before first running compile)

```
\sbt-tutorial
   \test
      build.sbt
```

after running sbt compile on this empty build.sbt file, I change the structure to

```
\sbt-tutorial
   \test
      \src\main\scala\example\Hello.scala
      build.sbt
```

compile and run work, but ~compile doesn't detect initial file creation.

EDIT2: Changing an existing file does trigger recompilation.

Comment: Post your folder structure and your build.sbt file here.